# Change "max-edge-start"-value for ion-menu on specific page

Tags: html, angular, ionic4

I want to change the value of the "max-edge-start" (aka "maxEdgeStart") property for ion-menu, depending on the page. I'm using the sidemenu template and writing all the code for the menu in app.component.html. According to the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu#properties), the default is set to 50px, but I want to reduce it to 0px while on a specific page without setting it manually in that page.

Here is some code I have tried:

```
<ion-menu type="overlay" contentId="content" 
[maxEdgeStart]="{selectedUrl === '/myUrl'? '0': '50'}">
```

and:

```
<ion-menu type="overlay" contentId="content" 
max-edge-start="{{selectedUrl === '/myUrl'? '0': '50'}}">
```

I would like to make it something similar to this expression:

```
<ion-menu <property>="{<if condition>? <then value>: <else value>}">
```

Errors corresponding to code examples:

```
Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 15 in 
[{selectedPath === '/myUrl'? '0': '50'}] in ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@2:49
```

and:

```
Can't bind to 'max-edge-start' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-menu'.
1. If 'ion-menu' is an Angular component and it has 'max-edge-start' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-menu' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting the `{ }` I think it's expecting JSON which is why its saying expected `:` after the end of `selectedPath` (col 15).

Your `[maxEdgeStart]` is correct.

To keep it clean you should do this in the code, so just:

```
<ion-menu type="overlay" contentId="content" [maxEdgeStart]="getMaxEdgeStart()">
```

Then in the ts code file for that page put your function in:

```
getMatchEdgeStart():number {
    return this.selectedUrl === '/myUrl' ? 0: 50;
}
```

If that doesn't work then it's likely to do with your `selectedUrl` value as I don't know where you're pulling that in from.